# How do i get this Bib file right?

Tags: biblatex

Right now I have the following BibTeX file:

```
@Article{PLT,
    author  = {Carmen C. Centena, Mitre C. Dourado und 
   Jayme L. Szwarcfiter},
    title   = {On the Convexity of Paths of Length Two in Undirected Graphs},
    URL = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571065309000043},
    year    = {2009},
 }  



@Article{RIGP,
author  = {Mitre C. Dourado, Lucia D. Penso, Dieter Rautenbach und Jayme L. Szwarcfiter},

title   = {Reversible Iterative Graph Processes},

journal = {Theor. Comput. Sci. 460: 16-25 },

year    = {2012},

}

@Article{IVE,

author  = {Carmen C. Centena, Lucia D. Penso, Dieter Rautenbach und Vinicius G. P. de Sá},

title   = {Immediate versus Eventual Conversion: Comparing Geoteic and Hull Numbers in $P_{3}$-Convexity},

URL = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397512005798},

year    = {2010},
}
```

I d like to see this in the PDF pretty much as I have written in here. Which `\bibliographystyle` should I use and do I need some extra packages?

Comment: Which bibliography style is pretty is a very subjective issue. This is mostly determined where you are going to submit your paper or thesis. If your case is none of these, please try one of acm, ieeetr, plain and see which looks _prettiest_ in your eyes. IMHO, it is difficult to produce ugly document in LaTeX. And welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4):

There are several weak points in your bib file.

1. Authors must be separated by the keyword *and*
2. There are separate fields for the volume number and the pages
3. Accents should be specified “the old way” because encoding problems may arise and sorting wouldn't work correctly anyway.
4. Words or parts of the title that must preserve their case should be surrounded by braces (the math formula is an example).

```
@Article{PLT,
  author  = {Carmen C. Centena and Mitre C. Dourado and Jayme L. Szwarcfiter},
  title   = {On the Convexity of Paths of Length Two in Undirected Graphs},
  URL     = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571065309000043},
  year    = {2009},
 }

@Article{RIGP,
  author  = {Mitre C. Dourado and Lucia D. Penso and Dieter Rautenbach and Jayme L. Szwarcfiter},
  title   = {Reversible Iterative Graph Processes},
  journal = {Theor. Comput. Sci.},
  volume  = {460},
  pages   = {16-25},
  year    = {2012},
}

@Article{IVE,
  author  = {Carmen C. Centena and Lucia D. Penso and Dieter Rautenbach and Vinicius G. P. de S{\'{a}}},
  title   = {Immediate versus Eventual Conversion: Comparing Geoteic and Hull Numbers in {$P_{3}$}-Convexity},
  URL     = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397512005798},
  year    = {2010},
}
```

Alternatively, the authors can be specified `surname, name(s)`:

```
  author  = {Centena, Carmen C. and Dourado, Mitre C. and Szwarcfiter, Jayme L.},
```

What bib style should you use? It depends on many factors and no definitive answer can be given. You could use

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

and

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

to have good flexibility. Or you might give an eye to `biblatex`.

Comment: One potentially interesting thing, with biber, you can change the name and list separators recognised in the .bib (with the `--namesep` and `--listsep` options). So you can in fact do `--namesep=und` ...

Comment: @PLK Nice to know.

Comment: Hi Greg,thx for you answer. Everything worked out fine, but somehow i don't get the pages to show up. It tells me there is a mistake with it, but i don't see why. Any clues?

Comment: @user34047 Sorry, there was a missing trailing comma in the line `volume = {460}`

Answer (score 4):

I would use `biblatex` and `biber`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[german,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber,maxbibnames=10]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}\space}}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

with bib file:

```
@Misc{IVE,
  author =   {Centena, Carmen C. and Penso, Lucia D.  and
                  Rautenbach, Dieter and de Sá, Vinicius G. P.},
  title =    {Immediate versus Eventual Conversion: Comparing
                  Geoteic and Hull Numbers in $P_{3}$-Convexity},
  url =
                  {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397512005798},
  year =     2010
}

@Misc{PLT,
  author =   {Centena, Carmen C.  and Dourado, Mitre C.  and
                  Szwarcfiter, Jayme L.},
  title =    {On the Convexity of Paths of Length Two in
                  Undirected Graphs},
  url =
                  {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571065309000043},
  year =     2009
}  

@Article{RIGP,
  author =   {Dourado, Mitre C.  and Penso, Lucia D.  and
                  Rautenbach, Dieter and Szwarcfiter, Jayme L.},
  title =    {Reversible Iterative Graph Processes},
  journal =  {Theor. Comput. Sci.},
  volume =   460,
  pages =    {16--25},
  year =     2012
}
```

Many of the points in egreg's excellent answer apply.  `biblatex`/`biber` has the advantage that you can use utf8, it will recognise a german document and more customization is available.  You will find several other questions here describing that.  The one customization I have made above is to remove the `In:` that is standard `biblatex` style, but is foreign to me.